# How Can I Tell If My Site Is Running ASP.NET MVC or Web Forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I am a non-coder that needs to get some information to my developer.  One of the questions was whether we were running ASP.NET MVC or Web Forms?  What is the best way I can tell this.  If you want to take a look, the site is at http://sokanu.com (just a splash page)

Thanks guys

Comment: ha... tricksy way to get people to click on your website! :p

Answer (score 9):

It's running WebForms.

You can tell by the Viewstate in the page source.

Answer (score 7):

Check the HTTP response headers. ASP.NET MVC 1.0 generated pages will have:

```
X-Aspnetmvc-Version:1.0
```

Comment: Note that you should still be getting `X-Powered-By` and `X-AspNet-Version`, but ASP.NET MVC will add that third header.

Comment: Are you know this information can blocked by server and you can't say that site made in asp.net mvc.

Comment: True, the same as well with VIEWSTATE (you can disable them) and URL (there's URL Rewriter module). There is no 100% surefire way to tell.

Answer (score 2):

As SLaks says, you can tell it is Web Forms because the page has a `__VIEWSTATE` field. Because it is a splash page, the view-state is nearly empty and the page does not need to be Web Forms at all. You need to look at the rest of the site to ascertain how much Web Forms and code is there. You can definitely mix Web Forms and MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Also, (although not concrete), typically with a WebForms application, you're pages end with .aspx extensions, and with MVC you benefit from pretty urls.

Comment: Well WebForm pages not necessarily end with .aspx... default pages don't, and URL rewriting may as well be used to change this behaviour.